# Vuetify toolbar is not collapsing on mobile view

Tags: vuetify.js

I am reading the official docs of Vuetify toolbar, I want to use the toolbar provided in the example but when I use the mobile view from dev tools and click the menu icon to expand it, it doesn't expand.

Here is [the example provided by official docs](https://codepen.io/tarekhassan/pen/Logrxq)

Here is the code itself

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-toolbar>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the example you linked, the menu bar does not open either because there is no method to implement it.

In this vuetify example, the menu bar that opens and closes correctly in desktop and mobile.

What they did was implement @click right there in the HTML

```
    <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
```